# warning: implicitly reading from a sync is deprecated; apply a '.read??()' method

Tags: chapel

I just upgraded from chapel 1.23 to 1.24. Now the compiler screams at me;

> warning: implicitly reading from a sync is deprecated; apply a
> '.read??()' method

For example. the code block below lists this warning at the last line.

```
var allStatesLock$: sync bool;
allStatesLock$.writeXF(true);                
allStatesLock$;
```

**.read??()** does not seam to be a method in chapel 1.24.

Comment: I think they mean something like readFF() or readXX()

Comment: You are right. I am using sync variables as locks. What I need to do is: 

  allStatesLock$.readFE();

Answer (score 1):

@ahysing: Sorry for the confusion caused by this error message.  As @Noah correctly mentions in the comments, the `??` here is meant to be a placeholder for various options like `FE`, `FF`, or `XX`.

In Chapel 1.24.0, implicit accesses to synchronization variables were deprecated for reasons documented in the Chapel 1.23.0 release notes (starting on slide 6 of the [Ongoing Efforts deck](https://chapel-lang.org/releaseNotes/1.23/05-ongoing.pdf)).  Replacing implicit reads with `.readFE()` and implicit writes with `.writeEF(val)` should keep your code working without warnings.